# How to remove Google login username from Chrome profile name?

Tags: google-chrome

I have 20 Chrome profiles, sorted by the name I gave. However when I login with any profile to Google services it will attach Google username to this profile and to make even worse it attach the name before the name I gave so sorting is ruined. Renaming Google profile won't work, it always keeps that username. Is there any way to remove this?
[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots to your question so we can see where is this happening.

Comment: Added it now to the post